# single API call with parallel logic in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

This is my code, here I need make "GetId" API call in parallel for better performance for my custom API. How do I make this?

```
foreach (ResponseModel AccountSwap in invalidRecords)
        {
            this.ValidatePolicyExist(AccountSwap, bpValidPolicyDataTable);
        }



private void ValidatePolicyExist(ResponseModel policyDetails, DataTable ValidDataTable)
        {
                if (this.IsPolicyExist(policyDetails.CorrectPolicyNumber))
                {
                    var row = ValidDataTable.NewRow();
                    row["IncorrectReference"] = policyDetails.IncorrectNumber;
                    row["CorrectReference"] = policyDetails.CorrectNumber;
                    ValidDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
                }
       }

        private bool IsPolicyExist(string policyNumber)
        {
            var accountId = GetId(policyNumber).Result; // This API will return BIGINT number as a response if the records exist
            return accountId != null;
        }


    public class ResponseModel
    {
        public string IncorrectNumber { get; set; }
        public string CorrectNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I make the “GetId()” API call in parallel call? by doing this my API will be bit faster.
I tried doing without parallel it takes 28 seconds for 100 records, but this is more time – we need to reduce to less than 10 second

Comment: You don't show the implementation of `GetId`, how can anyone suggest anything about parallelization. You do know that in some cases, doing things in parallel can slow stuff down, right? Is `GetId` `async`? Calling `.Result` on an `async` result can deadlock

Answer (score 0):

To make parallel API calls using asynchronous programming, you can use the Task.WhenAll method to execute multiple asynchronous operations concurrently. In your case, you want to make parallel API calls for the GetId method. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
// ...

// Your existing code...

private async Task<bool> IsPolicyExistAsync(string policyNumber)
{
    var accountId = await GetId(policyNumber); // This API will return BIGINT number as a response if the records exist
    return accountId != null;
}

// ...

// Inside your main method or wherever you're using this logic...

var tasks = invalidRecords.Select(accountSwap => IsPolicyExistAsync(accountSwap.CorrectNumber));
var policyExistenceResults = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

for (int i = 0; i < invalidRecords.Count; i++)
{
    if (policyExistenceResults[i])
    {
        var row = bpValidPolicyDataTable.NewRow();
        row["IncorrectReference"] = invalidRecords[i].IncorrectNumber;
        row["CorrectReference"] = invalidRecords[i].CorrectNumber;
        bpValidPolicyDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

A few things to note:

1. I've changed **IsPolicyExist** to **IsPolicyExistAsync** to make it
   an asynchronous method returning a **Task**.
2. Inside your main method, you can use **Task.WhenAll** to run all the
   **IsPolicyExistAsync** tasks concurrently. This will help improve performance by executing the API calls in parallel.
3. After awaiting the **Task.WhenAll**, you'll have an array of boolean
   results that indicate whether each policy exists or not.
4. You can then iterate through the **invalidRecords** and
   **policyExistenceResults** arrays to decide whether to add rows to **bpValidPolicyDataTable**.

Please make sure your API methods (**GetId** and others) are properly designed to support asynchronous operations. Also, remember to handle exceptions and asynchronous concurrency carefully, as they can introduce their own complexities.